# Another eval() victim

Tags: php, eval

Some code uses `eval()` to execute code stored in an array like this:

```
// $oOwner is an object
$strId = "abc";
$strClass = "someClass";
$aParams = array('a' => 'atext', 'b' => 'btext');

$this->menu = array(
"Entry 1" => ' openForm(\$oOwner,\$strId,\$strClass,\$aParams); ',
// ...
);
```

The values of the array's keys will be given directly into an `eval()` function.

Now I get an error: `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING ... eval()'d code on line 1`

What is the problem?

---

**EDIT:**

Loop through the array and `eval()` the values:

```
eval( $this->menu[$param[0]] );
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Now: `"Entry 1" => " openForm(\$this->owner,\$strId,\$strClass,\$aParams); "`

Using double quotes `"..."` leads to `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: strId in ... : eval()'d code on line 1`. Also for the other variables.

`

Comment: Your code does not contain any `eval()`.

Comment: Try swapping the eval for an echo, and making sure the command you're running is correct - you might need to use double quotes around the values of your array, else your variables won't be interpolated.

Comment: Added the `eval()` code.

Comment: @andrewsi when using echo instead of eval, I get `openForm(\$this->owner,\$strId,\$strClass,\$aParams);`

Comment: @Azincourt - see Baba or danilosir's answers. You need to use double quotes - using single quotes means the street is treated as literal and your variables aren't added in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I tried always led to errors and I came up with the idea of putting the array in there as a string via `var_export()`.

There are 2 attempts posted here:
[Store array in a string to eval() later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568095/store-array-in-a-string-to-eval-later)

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quote `'` so you don't need to use `\$` in your variables

Prof of Concept use both single and double quotes

```
function openForm(){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}

$strId = "abc";
$strClass = "someClass";
$aParams = array('a' => 'atext', 'b' => 'btext');
$oOwner = "ABC" ;

$menu = array(
"Entry 1" => ' openForm($oOwner,$strId,$strClass,$aParams); ',
"Entry 2" => " openForm(\$aParams,\$strId); "
);

eval($menu["Entry 1"]);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
  1 => string 'abc' (length=3)
  2 => string 'someClass' (length=9)
  3 => 
    array
      'a' => string 'atext' (length=5)
      'b' => string 'btext' (length=5)


array
  0 => 
    array
      'a' => string 'atext' (length=5)
      'b' => string 'btext' (length=5)
  1 => string 'abc' (length=3)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when using `=> " openForm(\$this->owner,\$strId,\$strClass,\$aParams); "` then I get `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: strId` when using `"`

Comment: its because `$strId` was not defined .. you can see i had to define all your variables  to make mine work

Comment: Of course they are defined: `$aParams = json_decode($this->owner->getParams(), true);
        $strClass = $this->owner->getClassName();
        $strId    = $this->owner->getId();` I did not want to post all my code...

Comment: What do you mean by "was not defined"? Those are the real values, and I have defined them initially as dummy data in my question post.

Comment: `PHP Notice: Undefined variable` is a standard error when a variable has not been defined or declared ... try `$strId = null ;` before you call eval

Comment: That was just for test to show you that your code is not working because you did not declare it properly

Comment: I do not understand your point, I did declare it. So how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried double quotes when declaring code to be eval?

```
// ...
$this->menu = array(
"Entry 1" => " openForm(\$oOwner,\$strId,\$strClass,\$aParams); ",
// ...
);
```

Comment: Yes then I get: `Undefined variable: aParams ` and `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: strId in`, ... on `eval()'d code on line 1`