# Store array in a string to eval() later

Tags: php, arrays, eval

Having problems with `eval()`. I am forced to store strings in an array that are exectuted later on.

Now, storing strings in the string is no problem. But how do I store an array in there? Since I will NOT have access to the variable, I want the array directly stored to this string.

See this code:

```
    // ----------------------
    // -- class A
    $strId    = 'id_1234';
    $strClass = 'classname';
    $arParams = array('pluginid' => 'monitor', 'title' => 'Monitor', ...);

    $strClone = 'openForm(desktop(),"'.$strId.'","'.$strClass.'",'.$arParams.');';

    $this->menu = array( "clone" => $strClone, ... );

    // ----------------------
    // -- class B
    // loop through $this->menu, then..
    {
      eval( $this->menu[$item] );
    }

    // ----------------------
    // -- class C
    function openForm( $owner, $id, $class, $params )
    {
      ...
    }
```

Everything works perfectly except for the array `$arParams`.

`There is an error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' in ... (441) : eval()'d code on line 1`

What is the problem?
Can I do this without `serialize()`?

---

**EDIT:**

I have set up a representation of what is going on. If you get this to run, then it is fixed:

```
$ar = array('a' => 'value1', 'b' => 'value2');
$str = "something";

$run = " a('".$str."', \$ar); "; // this line may be changed

// this is done to represent the loss of the variables in another class
unset($ar);
unset($str);

// $run is kept
eval( $run );

function a($str, $ar) {
    echo "\$str="         . $str      . "<br>";
    echo "\$ar['a']="     . $ar['a']    . "<br>";
    echo "\$ar['b']="     . $ar['b']    . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: There will almost definitely be a way to solve your problem without using eval(). Could you post more about why you think you need it?

Comment: We use that strange "framework" and are not to change it, only if absolutely necessary. I could solve it without it too.

Comment: So how can I do it that `eval()` way?

Comment: You need to provide more information about what classes A, B and C are.

Comment: I have added an representation of the whole code, please see it.

Comment: If you're forced into using eval(), I would say, it is now absolutely necessary to, either get a new framework or rewrite that part in the one you're using. This will end up costing you a lot in the long run, both in security, development time and headaches.

Comment: I cannot do that, however I am now using a hack, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're running the function `a()` in your `eval`'ed string, the variable `$ar` doesn't exist anymore. That's triggering an error, which causes the `eval()` to fail.

Since you're using `eval()`, a quick-and-dirty hacky way to fix it seems appropriate. ;-)

Instead of doing this:

```
$run = " a('".$str."', \$ar); ";
```

You can do this:

```
$run = " a('$str', ". var_export($ar, true) ."); ";
```

This will cause the string $run to look like this if you were to `echo` it:

```
a('something', array(
  'a' => 'value1',
  'b' => 'value2',
));
```

So now you're passing the array directly into the function call, instead of passing a variable.

Comment: That is what I came up too however a bit longer. I will use this attempt, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change `$arParams` to this:

```
$arParams = 'array("pluginid" => "monitor", "title" => "Monitor", ...)';
```

Comment: This does not work, I then get a `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`

Comment: The error is always in the `eva()` line. Please see my edit, I have added a code example.

Answer (score 0):

I now use this hack:

```
$strParams = " array(";
foreach($arParams as $strKey => $strVal) {
   $strParams .= "'".$strKey."' => '".$strVal."',";
}
$strParams = substr($strParams, 0, -1) . ") ";

// later on
... => " openForm(desktop(),'".$strId."','".$strClass."',".$strParams."); "
```